# Nearby search in objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, geolocation, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I would like to build an backend application on App Engine using Datastore and Objectify to store places (in java).

A place has latitude and longitude coordinates. Now I want to query places that are "near by" (a radius of 100 kilometers) the users position.

In SQL I would compute the distance in the SELECT statetment.
But something like this is not possible in Datastore using Objectify right?

So from what I saw from other projects is to make something like hashes of geo-areas right and store the hashes as string in a list, and check if two geo coordinates have the same geo aread hashes ...

For instance I have found this project called [java geo model](https://code.google.com/p/javageomodel/) but it seems that this project is no longer maintained and Im looking for something that can be used in production, in a real world application

Does anyone knows such a library or tutorial sites about this topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer, as already mentioned, is to use the Search API. However, you can find an example of using Objectify with geohashes here:  http://www.motomapia.com/

It uses the javageomodel code. Since the algorithm for [geohashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) hasn't changed, I wouldn't be too concerned about the code being old. However, it inherently doesn't produce very accurate results - at least not as accurate as what you will get with the search API.

Geographic indexing is not an easy problem. Computing a distance in your SELECT is not a scalable solution even in an RDBMS unless you have specialized indexes ala PostGIS.

Answer (score 1):

The [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/query_strings#Java_Queries_on_geopoint_fields) allows for searching based on distance.

Comment: Hm, good point! Thanks! But some points are not clear to me: can I query Datastore with the Search API? From what I see from the documentation the Search API works with Documents (com.google.appengine.api.search.Document, Indexes and Fields)
So I have to "mirror" my data from datastore / objectify to Documents in Search API to make it searchable through Search API?

Comment: _"So I have to "mirror" my data from datastore / objectify to Documents in Search API to make it searchable through Search API?"_ Correct. They are separate places to store data and they don't communicate directly with each other. You need to manually go through your datastore and add pieces of data into what the Search API calls "documents". The basics are [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/)

Comment: You can use the task queue (and transactionally enqueued tasks) to ensure that the data in the search system stays consistent with data in the datastore.

Comment: @stickfigure Can you upload a doc via the search API inside of an objectify transaction? If not, do you mean to say that to ensure proper data consistency you should use a task queue inside of a objectify transaction that then calls a servlet which uploads a doc via the Search API?

Comment: When I write a transaction that modifies data which needs to be replicated into the search API, I transactionally add a "sync this entity" deferred task. The task just has the key of the entity; it loads the entity and syncs whatever is appropriate to the search api.

Comment: @stickfigure I see, Makes sense. How scalable is this model though? Imagine a very popular app where you make a lot of datastore entity puts, which in turn each have a Search API GeoPoint doc to put as well. Couldn't the Task Queue get backed up and lag behind the datastore puts? My users expect their entity (with location) to be available now, not waiting for the task to finish. Do you know if it possible to scale the Task Queue proportionally with the datastore so puts to both are made as soon as physically possible?

Comment: Your question is certainly not about the task queue, which can scale quite far (500/s per queue, sharded across dozens of queues...). The bigger question is how many updates per second can you make to a search index. That I do not know.

Comment: @stickfigure I investigated further. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41288486/3075340 Basically, there is a 15,000 per minute (250/second) limit on doc puts and deletes. So... looks like it can't really scale that proportionally with the datastore if an app got really popular.

Comment: Geo searching is a hard problem. On the plus side, it's just an indexing problem - you can always move to a more scalable index solution without dramatically changing your architecture. The search API is really easy to get started with and maybe gives you enough runway? I don't know of any other solutions that can get you up and running in a few dozen lines of code. The geohashing solution that motomapia uses is not great.