# Google Cloud Search API - is there a limit to number of document puts per second?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

With the Google Cloud [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/training/fts_intro/lesson2) is there a limit or restriction to how many documents you can add to a search index per second?

I know the Search API is great for querying and scales well that way, but what about many individual document puts per second? Would using a unique index for each document put improve performance?

The reason I ask is because of an application I will be building that will have many Datastore puts with one respective Search document put right after the Datastore entity gets put. I am wondering if the Search API is as robust as the Datastore when it comes to many puts per second. I'd like to scale both linearly as the application grows rather than use a Task Queue to sync the Search document with the Datastore entity later.

The nature of my application calls for both the entity and document to be put at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this at the bottom of the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/):

> The Search API imposes these limits to ensure the reliability of the
> service. These apply to both free and paid apps:
>
> Maximum query usage: 100 aggregated minutes of query execution time per
> minute
>
> Maximum documents added or deleted:   15,000 per minute

So it looks like there is a safety limit that works out to be about 250 writes/deletes per second. That would not be able to keep up with the Datastore if the app kept growing and growing.

If anyone has any more information on this please comment/answer. Thank you :)

Comment: You can have limits raised if you need it (according to a support request asked a while back).